# Two Mongoid models stored in one MongoDB collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

This is something I want to do but I can't figure out if it is possible.
I would have two Ruby classes (SuperNes and MegaDrive) that include the same Module (Console). 
So I assume there will be common attributes and a few particular ones. I would like to store it in the same MongoDB Collection (with the `store_in` helper).

How will I ensure that, for example, `SuperNes.all` will return only SuperNes data and not MegaDrive ?

Thank you for your answers and for the time you spent reading me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try inheritance in [mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html) ,

Comment: It was saying in the documentation that use of different models for the same collection would assign the attribute _type. (That would store the ruby type information) But that does nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

```
class Console
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class SuperNes < Console
end

class MegaDrive < Console
end
```